# WIFI Adapter on Lenovo T440 with Ubuntu 16.10, in DOWN state, cannot change state

Tags: lenovo, 16.10, xfce, intel-wireless

This issue started yesterday, and before then had been working just fine for months.

When I boot my computer, it will autoconnect to the nearest wifi, when I go to check the connection or change the network it tries to connect to, the list of available networks dissapears.

Within BASH, when i use ip link, it shows the device as being down. I attempted to bring the device back up using both ifconfig and ip link, both situations when run with sudo show no result. Normally this would indicate to me that the commands ran without incident, yet the device state remains DOWN.

I toggled the wifi kill switch on the PC on and off and noted that it produces and RF KILL error when I attempt to turn the device into an UP state, which is why I assume that is not part of the issue.

I downloaded the application wifi-radar the other day and am wonder if maybe this may have messed up some device control inheritance somehow and theres a config file I should look in.

Any help on this issue would be great. I honestly am excited to learn how to fix this particular problem.

I have a Lenovo T440 with a Intel Corp Wireless 7260 network controller.

Answer (score 0):

More research pulled up instances where users found killing the network-manager service and restarting it fixed the issue momentarily. I was able to confirm this is a valid work around.

To solve the issue i completely purged network-manager and reinstalled it. after a reboot network-manager is not crashing when I attempt to connect to a new network.

Since I completely removed the application this may have after effects that I'm not aware of. So far everything seems to be working fine.